# Why does Object::try work if it's sent to a nil object?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activesupport

If you try to call a method on a `nil` object in Ruby, a `NoMethodError` exception arises with the message:

```
"undefined method ‘...’ for nil:NilClass"
```

However, there is a [`try`](http://apidock.com/rails/Object/try) method in Rails which just return `nil` if it's sent to a `nil` object:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'active_support/all'

nil.try(:nonexisting_method) # no NoMethodError exception anymore
```

So how does `try` work internally in order to prevent that exception?

Comment: "If you try to call a method on a `nil` object ... exception arises" => Wrong. "If you try to call a method **undefined for `NilClass`** on `nil` ... exception arises" => Correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ActiveSupport 4.0.0 defines two `try` methods: [one](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/b4fa6516c1fc81f7da2a92adee9634d2771b7df0/activesupport/lib/active_support/core_ext/object/try.rb#L41) is for `Object` instances:

```
class Object
  def try(*a, &b)
    if a.empty? && block_given?
      yield self
    else
      public_send(*a, &b) if respond_to?(a.first)
    end
  end
end
```

the [other](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/b4fa6516c1fc81f7da2a92adee9634d2771b7df0/activesupport/lib/active_support/core_ext/object/try.rb#L71) is for `NilClass` instances (`nil` objects):

```
class NilClass
  def try(*args)
    nil
  end
end
```

Now, suppose we have an `Object` instance (excluding `nil`, which actually inherits from `Object`, like everything else in Ruby), defining a method which returns `nil`:

```
class Test
  def returns_nil
    nil
  end
end
```

So, running `Test.new.try(:returns_nil)` or `Test.new.not_existing_method`, `Object#try` gets called, which checks if a public method exists (the `respond_to?`); if it does it calls the method (the `public_send)`, otherwise it returns `nil` (there aren't other lines).

If we call another `try` on of these returning `nil` methods:

```
Test.new.try(:returns_nil).try(:any_other_method)
Test.new.try(:not_existing_method).try(:any_other_method)
```

we call `NilClass#try`, which is `nil#try`, which simply ignores everything and returns `nil`. So any other `try` is called on a `nil` instance and returns `nil`.

Answer (score 3):

Like every other object in Ruby, `nil` has a class ([`NilClass`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/NilClass.html)), which has methods. For instance, `nil?` is defined on `NilClass` to return true, which is why `nil.nil?` doesn't return a `NoMethodError`.

Every class in ruby can be *opened* (updated with new methods). Rails opens `NilClass` to add the `try` method and have it return `nil` (which is also why `try` can be chained even when one step in the chain returns `nil`, because that subsequent `nil` *also* responds to `try`).

Answer (score 2):

From Rails (3.2) [documentation](http://apidock.com/rails/Object/try):

```
  # Object#try:
  def try(*a, &b)
    if a.empty? && block_given?
      yield self
    else
      __send__(*a, &b)
    end
  end

  # NilClass#try (http://apidock.com/rails/NilClass/try):
  def try(*args)
    nil
  end
```

Method `try` is simply implemented separately for `nil` object so it always returns `nil`, even if the method you try to call is implemented for `nil` object.

Answer (score 1):

It ignores the argument and just returns `nil`. Here's the [implementation](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/3-2-stable/activesupport/lib/active_support/core_ext/object/try.rb#L54):

```
class NilClass
  def try(*args)
    nil
  end
end
```

Note that this implementation always returns `nil`, even if `nil` responds to the method:

```
nil.try(:to_i) # => nil, rather than 0
```